# Align div at bottom of div container

Tags: html, css

I know this question came up many times but none of the suggested solutions is working for me so I opened up a code sandbox and made an example.

**What I want**

I want to place an item at the bottom of a div that already has some children. In my code sandbox the desired div to place at the bottom has a className of `note__actions`.

**What I tried**

- Setting the container to `position: relative` and the item to `position: absolute`
- Using flexbox and setting the container to `display: flex` and the item to `align-self: flex-end`
- Multiple other things like vertical-align, and making empty items to fill up the space in-between

**Div setup**

```
<div className="flexBoxContainer" />
    <div className="item">
        <div>Header</div>
        <div>Title</div>
        <div>Paragraph</div>
        <div className="bottom__item">Actions>/div> // Only this div should go to the bottom of the "item" div
    </div>
</div>
```

**Sandbox**

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-sound-wf166?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Which element of your Sandbox do you wish to place at the bottom exactly ?

Comment: the div with the `className="note__actions"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using `flexbox` which is great. Now, use `margin-top:auto` on  `note__actions` to push the div to the bottom.

```
.note__actions {
  margin-top: auto;  
}
```

Comment: Such a simple change but a great result, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Give the container `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` - that will pull the content from top to bottom. If you want only the last item on the bottom and the rest on the top, wrap the rest with a div, like

```
<div className="flexBoxContainer" />
    <div className="item">
        <div>
            <div>Header</div>
            <div>Title</div>
            <div>Paragraph</div>
        </div>
        <div className="bottom__item">Actions>/div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I only want to place the last item at the bottom. I know what you want to do, thanks for your answer. Why is `align-self: flex-end` or any other solution not working?

Comment: Because `flex-direction: column;` is essentially flipping the div sideways. That would work without it. Another solution for column is to stretch one of the divs to take a whole space, so for example you can give the "paragraph" div `flex-grow: 1;`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a grid for that.
Change this in your Style on codesandbox.io:

```css
.note {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 211);
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 24px;
  display: grid;
  /*flex-direction: column;*/
  grid-template-rows: 50px 80px 1fr 80px;  /* height: 100%; */
  /* align-items: flex-end; */
  /* position: relative; */
}

.note__actions_bot {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I recommend this awesome Video to get a nice overview and some hint's how to do, and when to use which one of flex, grid and other solutions:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qm0IfG1GyZU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so you think working with `display: grid` is the better approach here? Your video explanations are very welcome as I most of the time use flex and this will help to open my approach to other solutions.

Comment: Your video links are both the same.

Comment: Grid becomes very handy if you need full-height layouts where stuff fill-up till the buttons. 
In the Video you see many suggestions. I think there is no rule to better use grid or flexbox. 
The point is: Choose the right tool which fit best for the given issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `flex: 1;` to the flexible content, for instance

```css
.note {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 211);
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.note-content {
  flex: 1;
}

.note-action {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="note">
  <div>Peter Holbert - 09. Jul 21 23:28</div>
  <div>Note Title</div>
  <div class="note-content">Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="note-action">Action 1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-top : auto` to the `note__actions` element